# How to create custom shortcuts to an Android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

Some applications give you the option to add a custom shortcut to the app through long-pressing the launcher screen ("add to homescreen" - "shortcuts"). They allow the app to be launched with a certain parameter or something, for example a shortcut to a page you've bookmarked and it would open it directly in the browser.

How do I add something similar to my app?

Comment: You're better off creating a widget, as the API for this isn't documented. But here's someone who did it: http://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "Android App Widgets". Please research on Android App Widgets. see these links below http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html , 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html and then to start the appropriate applications you will have to create the intent filters. Hope this guides you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct then you are talking about [Android widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)